# Google Fonts not rendering on FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I am using google fonts on my style sheet as below:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');

.font1{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}

.font2{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
}
```

and in my html

```
<p class="font1">Some text here</p>
```

The text is rendered in proper font on Chrome and IE, having trouble getting it to render on Firefox. I checked the Font section on DOM Inspector on Firefox, it shows correctly as below

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Roboto"), local("Roboto-Regular"), url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2") format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0-FF, U+131, U+152-153, U+2C6, U+2DA, U+2DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

What could be the reason? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Font Awesome not working in Firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831664/font-awesome-not-working-in-firefox-ie?rq=1)

Check out the above question.There seems to be a working fix for this issue.

> You need to add a local rule if you want Firefox to use the font when installing on the computer. See https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/CSS/@font-face.

```
@font-face { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; src: local(''FontAwesome'); }
```

Comment: I am not trying to use the font from local installation. Any ways i tried both

font-face { font-family: 'Roboto'; src: local('Roboto'); }
and
font-face { font-family: 'Roboto'; src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'); }

both did not work

Comment: Interestingly, if you go to Google Fonts website, the font renders correctly, so I am sure I am doing something wrong with using the font on my css